# Different table column width in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, html-table, width, padding

```
<table class="schedule">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th id="first-column">#</th>
       <th>Monday</th>
       <th>Tuesday</th>
       <th>Wednesday</th>
       <th>Thursday</th>
       <th>Friday</th>
       <th>Saturday</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

and

```
table.schedule { 
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 900;
}

#first-column {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

cause the first column has 200+10+10=220px width in Firefox, but 180+10+10=200px in Chrome and Safari. I think the `width` shouldn't include `padding`, so Firefox is right? But anyway, how can I set the same column width across browsers?

**Edit:** the Chrome Developer Tools look like:
[image]

Comment: I see it as 200px even in Chrome! What version of the browser are you using? I know that in chrome for 'beautification' it does tend to add extra padding to some components like textarea etc., by default. You have explicitly overridden them.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a modern doctype specified as I'm not seeing the described behaviour on my end. For example use `<!DOCTYPE html>` to tell the browsers it's HTML5. For me the first column is 200px + padding on Firefox, Chrome and Safari.